# Datetime comparison in SQLite with unique format

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a requirement, wherein column having date time information must be compared against present date & time. If earlier then this particular record must be deleted.
I have progressed with below implementation, but not getting any error & expected behavior is not met.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
        Calendar nowCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        String strNowTime = dateFormat.format(nowCalendar.getTime());

        // Delete the records at Manager_Dashboard SQLiteDB
        String whereClause = "DATETIME(End_Time) < DATETIME(?)";
        String whereArgs[] = {strNowTime};

        dbOfflineRange.delete("Offline_Range",whereClause,whereArgs);
```

As you could notice, if I have a record with End_Time in text within SQLite table (as `30 Nov 2018 21:35`), then this should be compared against current datetime (as `30 Nov 2018 23:35`)

As End_Time being earlier than Now, I am expecting deletion. But its not happening.

Comment: That's not a format that sqlite [date and time](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) functions understand, so they return `null`, and it can't be compared sensibly -  '10 Nov ...' sorts before '20 Jun ...' for example.  Use a supported format. I stick with the Unix time in seconds for efficiency in storage space and comparison time - faster to compare integers than it is strings.

Answer (score 0):

The Date and Time SQL functions require the date to be in a recognised format.

> Time Strings A time string can be in any of the following formats:
>
> ```
> YYYY-MM-DD
> YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
> YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
> YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS
> YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM
> YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
> YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS
> HH:MM
> HH:MM:SS
> HH:MM:SS.SSS
> now
> DDDDDDDDDD
> ```
>
> [SQL As Understood By SQLite - Date And Time Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Your best(simplest) option would be to store them as YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM (i.e. change the SimpleDateFormat accordingly).

- Note you would not even need the datetime function as direct comparison of the values would result in the desired outcome.
- Storing the unix timestamp value would be the more efficient storage/processing time wise.

You can then use the strftime function to return the date in the format you wish.

Otherwise you can convert the store value to a recognised format using SQL functions such as substr and then do the comparison.
[SQL As Understood By SQLite - Core Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr)

here's an example of how you could handle data stored in DD MMM YYYY HH:MM format
assuming that the value to compare against is provided in YYYYMMDDHH:MM format :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Offline_Range;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Offline_Range (end_time);

-- Add some test data dd MMM yyyy HH:mm
INSERT INTO Offline_Range VALUES
    ('21 May 2018 10:30'),
    ('21 Jun 2018 10:30'),
    ('21 Jul 2018 10:30'),
    ('21 Aug 2018 10:30')
;
SELECT * FROM Offline_Range
    WHERE
        substr(end_time,8,4)||
        CASE
            WHEN instr(end_time,'Jan') THEN '01'
            WHEN instr(end_time,'Feb') THEN '02'
            WHEN instr(end_time,'Mar') THEN '03'
            WHEN instr(end_time,'Apr') THEN '04'
            WHEN instr(end_time,'May') THEN '05'
            WHEN instr(end_time,'Jun') THEN '06'
            WHEN instr(end_time,'Jul') THEN '07'
            WHEN instr(end_time,'Aug') THEN '08'
            WHEN instr(end_time,'Sep') THEN '09'
            WHEN instr(end_time,'Oct') THEN '10'
            WHEN instr(end_time,'Nov') THEN '11'
            WHEN instr(end_time,'Dec') THEN '12'
        END
        ||
        substr(end_time,1,2)||substr(14,5) 

            <  

        '2018062200:00' -- 22 Jun 2018 00:00 amended to suit i.e. the value input
```

This creates a table :-

[image]

The result from the query would be :-

[image]